# Pending Approval Process Instances of inactive Approval Process are not working as expected

Tags: approval-process, field-update, email-alert

We had a two-step Approval Process in our org. I had a requirement to remove the first step from the process, and for the second one to modify field updates. Based on [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000335231&type=1) I cloned the existing Approval Process, modified the steps, and activated a new one. The existing AP is now inactive.

```
Inactive: Submit -> Step 1 -> Step 2 -> Approved
Active: Submit -> Step 2 -> Approved
```

This works perfectly for records that are submitted for approval **after** these changes. Unfortunately, we have a few dozens of records that are in the middle of the process. Salesforce article above says:

> This should not affect the current records that had been submitted for approval prior to deactivating the approval process.

In reality, these pending instances seem to be partially broken. **Step 2** seems to work fine, but for **Step 1** only one of three actions is happening:

- Status Date Field Update - works
- Status Field Update - doesn't work
- Email Alert - doesn't work

This is happening both for Approve and Reject actions.

I captured logs for approval process steps. There are no errors or exceptions, and I clearly can see that for Step 1 only part of the actions are happening.

```
**Step 1**
12:06:39.0 (11558445)|WF_APPROVAL|Approve|[Account: some name]|Step 1 Action(Approval based on first response)
12:06:39.0 (11817492)|WF_SPOOL_ACTION_BEGIN|Approve
12:06:39.0 (57570315)|WF_FIELD_UPDATE|[Account: some name]|Field:Account: Status Date|Value:Wed Aug 03 00:00:00 GMT 2022|Id=some id

**Step 2**
12:31:13.0 (11043616)|WF_APPROVAL|Approve|[Account: some name]|Step 2 Action(Approval based on first response)
12:31:13.0 (11169021)|WF_SPOOL_ACTION_BEGIN|Approve
12:31:13.0 (18050267)|WF_FIELD_UPDATE|[Account: some name]|Field:Account: Status|Value:Approved|Id=some id
12:31:13.0 (18227928)|WF_FIELD_UPDATE|[Account: some name]|Field:Account: Status Date|Value:Wed Aug 03 00:00:00 GMT 2022|Id=some id
12:31:13.0 (18285101)|WF_RULE_INVOCATION|[Account: some name]
12:31:13.0 (18312483)|WF_EMAIL_ALERT|Id=some id
12:31:13.0 (23304780)|WF_EMAIL_SENT
```